# how to send multiple images with multer and upload to cloudinary

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, cloudinary

I'm trying to send multiple images to nodejs and upload them to Cloudinary using multer, not multiple images from one file input, but from different file inputs, like so:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="eventimage1" >
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="eventimage2" >
```

but I don't know if multer can do it. There are some solutions online but it doesn't apply to may case, I don't know if there is a way to manipulate this:

```
var upload = multer();
app.post('/PATH', upload.array('uploadedImages', 10),FUNCTION)
```

to solve the issue multer has.

this is what I'm currently working with:

```
var upload = multer();
app.post('/PATH', upload.single("Upload_event_image"),FUNCTION)
```

and sending it to Cloudinary this way:

```
const img = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
      public_id: `${Event_title}_eventImage${Event_owners_id}`,
    });
```

so my question is how can I get the multiple images with multer and send all of them using Cloudinary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `upload.any()` and create one upload request for each entry in `req.files`:

```js
app.post("/PATH", upload.any(), async function(req, res) {
  await Promise.all(
    req.files.map(file => cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.path, ...))
  );
  res.send(???);
});
```

The question is what you want in the response to that request.

Answer (score 0):

Danny from Cloudinary Support here.

Our Upload API doesn't currently support receiving multiple files at once. Instead, as we have quite a high concurrency rate, we would recommend using multiple threads to send many files at once.

You can also use asynchronous calls, and tell Cloudinary to do the upload in the background by adding the async parameter and setting it to true.

I hope this helps. If you wanted to discuss this further, I'd recommend [opening a support ticket with us directly](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new), and we'll be happy to assist :)

Comment: if i do somthing like 

`const img = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
      public_id:${Event_title}_eventImage${Event_owners_id},
    });`

twice wouldn't it work?